# How to asynchronously read a file in visual c++?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-10, c++-cx

I've been trying to read data from a file in a windows 10 application in c++.  However I'm struggling a great deal with structuring the asynchronous task correctly, and continually getting errors telling me the argument type for reading the data is incorrect.  I've been trying to use GetFileAsync and GetFileFromPathAsync to acquire my StorageFile, however ReadTextAsync(file) will not compile.

Here is the relevant section of code I've written:

```
   auto file = Windows::Storage::StorageFile::GetFileFromPathAsync("C:\\data.txt");
        concurrency::create_task(Windows::Storage::FileIO::ReadTextAsync(file)).then([this, file](concurrency::task<Platform::String^> task)
            {
                try
                {
                    Platform::String^ fileContent = task.get();
                }
            });
```

The error given is that 'file' is not the correct type for ReadTextAsync.  It is supposed to take in an IStorageFile, but when constructing my file in the way I tried above, it receives the type IAsyncOperation.

I was given some advice that the reason this is not correctly functioning is I did not include the path collection in the task, however I had issues trying to chain the tasks together to get the data.  I'm fairly sure I'm missing something fundamental, but any guidance on how to properly read data in would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

That is because `Windows::Storage::StorageFile::GetFileFromPathAsync` returns async operation which you should first execute, it will return `IStorageFile^`. This should look like below (I have not compiled it):

```
auto getFileAsync = Windows::Storage::StorageFile::GetFileFromPathAsync("C:\\data.txt");
create_task(getFileAsync).then([this](StorageFile^ sf){
   create_task(FileIO::ReadTextAsync(sf)).then([this](Platform::String^ text){
      // here use text
   });
});
```

Comment: Well, it is async - if you want it to be run immediately then you need to call `.get();` on task returned by create_task. Be carefull as you should not do it on GUI thread. I have made a minor code change in my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!  I can finally see the correct information reading in.  However, I'm trying to store this text locally in my program so I can later pass it into an algorithm.  Trying to set a variable outside of this task equal to 'text' yields a 

"an enclosing function local variable cannot be referenced in a lambda body unless it is in the capture list" error. 

 Is there any way for me to store these values to use after the task has completed?

Comment: @hnobuhisa you should capture your local variable in capture list i.e. [&mylocalvar], but if you execute your file reading task asynchronously then you should not capture local variables, but move this variable to enclosing class. For more on capture lists read here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda.

Comment: I'm afraid I've never even heard of a capture list before, I'm very new to the language.  There will be only one local variable for me to store, 'text', and I will only be running this asynchronous task once.  How do you recommend I setup the capture list to store the variable?  I apologize for relying so heavily on your help in this circumstance.

Comment: @hnobuhisa As I said - move this variable to the class from which method you execute file reading. If you put it inside the class, then it suffices to leave capture list as `[this]`.